# RDP to Windows Mobile device from PC

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, remote-desktop

I am in need of writing a program(s) that will allow me to remote in to a windows mobile device (WM6.1.4) and allow me to control (like the Remote Desktop Client on Windows XP/7).  I can remote *to* a Windows XP/7 pc from my mobile device but not vice versa and that's what I need.  I would also like to include a windows explorer feature to view/copy/delete files from a windows mobile device remotely.

Any ideas or leads as to what I would need to do to get this done? C# preferrably.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SOTI Pocket Controller](http://www.soti.net/PCPro/Default.aspx), though if you want "no frills" the [ActiveSync Remote Display](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=74473FD6-1DCC-47AA-AB28-6A2B006EDFE9&displaylang=en) powertoy may also fit the bill.

Comment: I'm currently using the [My Mobile](http://www.mymobiler.com) app on my device to connect remotely too it and it works pretty well.  It even includes a Windows Explorer feature to view files.  What I'd like to do is incorporate these features in to a device management app I've already created (I'd like everything in one program). Are there any Windows APIs I can call? I've seen RAPI but not too sure if that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, RAPI has an interface for file operations (along with some basic process and registry stuff).  The remote desktop isn't so simple - there are no public API sets for it that I'm aware of.