# Windows Mobile 6.0/6.5/Phone7 screen capturing in C#/C++

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I plan to develop a web based system for remote control of Windows Mobile/Phone computers. I did this for desktop Win32 using different approaches: 
1. Capturing using GDI
2. Capturing using so called Mirror Driver for better performance.

My question is how to do it on Windows Mobile 6.5/Phone 7. Is GDI capturing possible? How about performance since on desktop Windows because of VRAM/RAM access architecture transfer memory back from VRAM to RAM is costly?

Is RDP protocol API available on Windows Mobile/Phone 7? RDP Server?

Any hints are welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[RDP on Windows Mobile : How to Setup](http://pocketnow.com/how-to/tutorial-setting-up-remote-desktop-in-windows-mobile)

[RDP to Windows Mobile Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492349/rdp-to-windows-mobile-device-from-pc)

[Using GDI+ on Windows Mobile](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/10/31/using-gdi-on-windows-mobile.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but my question would be rather how do those applications work?

Comment: @dominolog: Your question was "Is GDI capturing possible?" and "Is RDP protocol API available on Windows Mobile/Phone 7?" - which I answered. If that is not what you want, then you need to rephrase and make a more concise question.

Comment: To be even more precise those 2 question you quote are related to previous statement "I plan to develop a web based system for remote control of Windows Mobile/Phone computers. I did this for desktop Win32 using different approaches: 1. Capturing using GDI 2. Capturing using so called Mirror Driver for better performance.". So anywaway I was asking how to screen capture usign GDI, not how to use GDI in Windows Mobile/Phone.

Comment: Summarizing the question. How to programatically make the screen shot effectively on Windows Mobile 6.0/6.5 and Windows Phone 7?